# Moderator declined my flag of an illegal question?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently flagged a question with a custom flag for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270256/include-javascript-into-pdf) which had a malicious intentions with making a virus. The OP even claimed this was going to be released and purposely inject this into a PDF to make profit, which is illegal.

Although my flag was declined by a moderator with a reason stating I should of just closed-voted:

> Post contains malicious intentions. – Spencer Wieczorek yesterday   declined - Why aren't you casting close votes. If it's closed it can be deleted, no need to wait for moderators to get involved.

Is the Moderator correct here that I should of close-voted instead of flagging?

Comment: You really need to tell the mod which action you want them to take. *Post contains malicious intentions* is an observation at best and not actionable. More chance on success: *This post only exists for malicious intentions and is best deleted. It is already/almost closed but I lack the privilege to delete it yet and an VLQ flag might be handled wrong by robo-reviewers. Can you delete it?*. But for blatant cases that need a delete vote mob you can also ask in the SOCVR chat room. Our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#general-expectations-for-members) does state we're open for `del-pls` requests.

Comment: Edit > Preferences > JavaScript > "Enable Acrobat JavaScript" checkbox.  That was useful, thanks.

Comment: I saw one of the mods marked the original question as a duplicate. But the [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9219807/5894241) is literally asking for off-site documentation. I have already cast my CV, but does anyone see any reason to leave it open?

Comment: Now this is BS. There is nothing in that question or the comments from the OP saying they wanted to make a virus. They want to know if it is possible to embed JavaScript in a PDF document. **That is a straightforward and answerable question**. Every person who commented to derail that post should be ashamed of themselves.

Comment: Holy crap, that question just got deleted with an active spam/rude abusive flag. There, are you guys happy? Y'all cost him 100 points and a red flag on his account because he asked a straightforward question. This is extremely disappointing. He is very likely now on the verge of being question banned as well. Why don't we break out the reddit style vengeance and find his home address somehow then go shame him at home? That sounds like a plan right?

Comment: @TinyGiant They didn't actually have any rep to lose from the flag, so they didn't lose any, but you are correct that the post certainly isn't abusive.

Comment: @TinyGiant it had a single rude abusive flag on it when the OP self-deleted - that's not enough to trigger the rep penalty (needs 6 flags or a single mod flag). It also shouldn't appear as a misleading audit as a post with only R/A flags aren't counted... Having said that if the OP wants to delete it, so be it... it was a possible duplicate by the looks of it. I have cleared up the comments though.

Comment: It still should never have had a rude abusive flag cast on it, and the OP should never have been shamed / pressured / abused into deleting their question @Jon. This chain of events is sickening.

Comment: It would be interesting to ask a lawyer if helping a malware author on SO could leave any liability for subsequent losses lying around, either for the users who helped or SO itself.

Comment: @TinyGiant Nobody pressured the user into deleting his question. If you read the comments then you should have seen that he was specifically going to include a script in an otherwise harmless file which would run something on the users computer that they did not consent to in order to earn money for the OP. What part of that isn't distribution of illegal malware?

Comment: Voting to close and flagging are not mutually exclusive actions. You could have done both.

Comment: @Ethan I did read the comments and there was nothing I saw that said he was going to do anything malicious, other than the obnoxious comments telling him that he must be trying to do something malicious. I did see that he was pressured into deleting his question not only by the obnoxious comments, but the massive pile of unwarranted downvotes. Good on you for sticking up for the bullies though.

Comment: @TinyGiant I'm with you that what happened there was ridiculous. That question could have well have had very innocent intents. I admit that the question did indeed link to what appeared to be a mining script, however if the user had not posted that specifically and just asked how to put Javascript in a PDF to run it, shown what they tried, etc. this would have been an okay question. I doubt anyone would have thrown a fit. This case was handled completely incorrectly, especially once brought up on Meta.

Comment: Well, the coin-mining script was a kinda clue...

Comment: @TinyGiant yeah, looks like it's some kind of bitcoin mining hijack, which is a s_tty thing to do to someone who is just opening a pdf. I don't really want to go to the mentioned website in the code to see exactly what it's doing, but it sure do look sketch.

Comment: Hmm, claims to never run without asking the user https://coinhive.com/documentation/authedmine cannot verify if true, nor behavior when executed in a PDF.

Comment: @TinyGiant Maybe they deleted their comments when you looked. But the OP of that post ***specifically*** stated they understood that what they where doing was illegal and wanted to create released malware anyways. Then also mentioned this was on their schools site and wanted to have their miner run on the PDF on other students computer when they visited the site so they can make a profit. That is both *illegal* and *malicious*, especially in a school setting. The question itself is fine but suspicious, but after OP clarified their intentions are malicious in the comments is when I flagged.

Comment: @Spencer without proof it didn't happen. I did not see anything to that extent, and you have provided no proof, so we're all just relying on you telling the truth, something I'm not willing to accept without some kind of evidence.

Comment: @TinyGiant But that **is** what happened. The only reason why I stated *"The OP even claimed this was going to be released and purposely inject this into a PDF to make profit"* in this Question is because that's what OP said *exactly* in the comments when I posted this. Unless a Moderator can pull deleted comments from this post I don't have access to deleted comments. I'm not sure why you think me and everyone else is just making up this *"story"*, I didn't take screenshots as I didn't think. The comments are no longer there so how exactly could I prove it? Why would I make that up?

Comment: @TinyGiant I cannot predict the future, I don't just go about taking screenshots of every comment I see in the event they are removed. The post was about my flag, not a court case against the user. I find it extremely bothering that you rather have this be a conspiracy and think everyone is lying in both the comments you mentioned and what I've stated to try and harm this user with no purpose.

Comment: But if you insist it appears @JonClements was the one who may of removed those comments, you can contact that mod and see if they have a copy of them before they where deleted.